# What resources are there for finding ONLINE writing partners?

Tags: resources, collaboration

I have been at looking at the different resources but many of them are for meetups in real life. What if I wanted to collaborate over the internet rather than face to face? Where could I go for that specifically?

Comment: When you say partners do you mean co-authors (as opposed to critique/review partners)?  That's how I read your question, but if I'm wrong could you please clarify?  Thanks.

Comment: No like writing partners but I could see that being helpful as well. I mean people who are equally working on a writing project and it's a shared thing.

Answer (score 2):

I am writing to offer an idea for a solution rather than a straight answer.

May I suggest that you register free with any number of writers' websites (you may already be a member of, for example, AWAIonline or WealthyWebWriter) to make a posting on one or all of their forums.

Happy Writing!